# Alerts, notifications, (status) messages - looking for real practical examples

Tags: usability, text, error-message, notification, messages

Are there somewhere real practical examples of texts for alerts, notifications and status messages? I thought of something like a library where you could search for an area and find ideas and examples?

I know there are lots of great guidelines on how to design your notifications. However, if English is not your native language it is sometimes hard for me to think of or come up with the right or creative words, so examples would be really helpful.

Just to check smaller texts like wether it was better to say "Add [username] to friends" vs. "Add [username] as a friend" you can google both phrases and see which one is more commonly used. However, as already said I was looking for inspirations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of sites that I like to use for general inspiration - I don't know of a site that's dedicated to error messages, but that sounds like a great business opportunity for somebody!

smileycat.com has a category for error messages: http://www.smileycat.com/design_elements/error_messages/

and PatternTap has a couple of tags that are in the neighborhood of what you're looking for: http://patterntap.com/tags/types